# Modifying the data of SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, simplecursoradapter

I extended SimpleCursorAdapter according to my needs. I want to show two textviews in a row.

One of these textviews is filled by the cursor but for the other one I want to use an ArrayList. Let me give an example to clarify:

[image]

For the first field I use the data from cursor

```
String[] columns = new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.toptext };
```

I want to use ArrayList for the second field so that they form the following listview

[image]

I don't know how I can set the second field. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but you could use the `_id` column of your query to map your values to the list and later bind the data.

```
private HashMap<Long, String> items = new HashMap<Long, String>(); // this will map the ids from the cursor to the values in the ArrayList
//get the cursor Cursor cursor = the query and then map the values:
int tmp = 0;
while (mc.moveToNext()) {
    items.put(mc.getLong(mc.getColumnIndex("_id")), extra.get(tmp)); //or replace _id with your ID column from the query
    tmp++;
}
```

Then pass this `HashMap` to your custom adapter constructor:

```
    private HashMap<Long, String> extraStuff; 

    public YourCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                    String[] from, int[] to, HashMap<Long, String> extraSutff) {
       // stuff
       this.extraStuff = extraStuff;
}
```

and bind the values in the `bindView()` method:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView top = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
    top.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(THE_COLUMN_FOR_THE_FIRST_TEXTVIEW)));
    TextView bottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
    bottom.setText(extraStuff.get(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(THE_ID_COLUMN_FROM_THE_QUERY))));
}
```

Note: I don't know how efficient this will be if you have many rows in the cursor.